# Can connect to FTP on Windows Server 2016 locally but not remotely

Tags: ftp, windows-server-2016

I have a Windows Server 2016 machine with FTP Server role installed, an FTP site added, and FTP Server rules added in Windows Firewall. I can connect via FTP locally like via command line like this:

```
ftp localhost  
Connected to *redacted*.  
220 Microsoft FTP Service  
200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.  
User (*redacted*:(none)): Administrator  
331 Password required  
Password:  
230 User logged in.
```

However, when I try to connect to the server's IP address via Filezilla on my own computer using both FTP or SFTP it tries to connect for a while then the connection times out. Anything I might be missing? Thanks.

Comment: Have you opened the port(s) on the firewall?

Comment: Well SFTP is not supported in IIS normally it would be FTPS as for remotely hitting FTP I would make sure you don't have a network firewall between your client and server.

Comment: You might have a local firewall at your pc or router preventing ftp connection. Or the issue might be with the remote's server topology. You should provide more details about your local network's and server's networking in order to receive more thatn a general help.

Comment: Would help, if you show us *verbose* FileZilla log file.

Comment: @Marco This is a VPS from 1and1.com running Windows Server 2016, so I assume that they have no firewalls that would block my connection.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Here's the log in verbose mode:  
Trace: CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()  
Trace: CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 0  
Status: Connecting to 74.208.244.146:21...  
Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity  
Trace: CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(2114)  
Trace: CControlSocket::ResetOperation(2114)  
Error: Could not connect to server

Comment: port 21 is closed on your IP, traceroute your IP from your client to make sure you know whats between your client and server. to rule out your windows firewall you might want to disable it for a quick test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make sure [FTP server rules in Windows firewall are enabled](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_ftps_server#window_firewall).
- Make sure you have [restarted the FTP server or whole system](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_ftps_server#restart) (is needed for the firewall rules to get applied)
- Maybe not be your immediate problem, but make sure that the [FTP server is configured with its external IP address](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_ftps_server#firewall).
- Your provider (1and1) will for sure have an external firewall/NAT that needs to be configured to allow the port 21.

*(disclaimer: the links go to my guide on [Installing a Secure FTP Server on Windows using IIS](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_ftps_server#firewall))*

Comment: All 3 server rules are enabled, I restarted the FTP service and also rebooted the machine, and I added its external IP address in the indicated position. Unfortunately, I still can not connect to the server via FTP.

Comment: Your last point was it. I assumed that my provider would have the port open by default, but I verified that the firewall policies on the hosting account itself did not have port 21 open. I created a rule to open it, and now I can connect via FTP (albeit I get another error which I'm looking into). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Once Port 21 is open for FTP, the user mentions another issue. I suspect the issue is with File Transfers. This is likely due to Port 20 not being open. Port 20 is used for data transfer.